# Organizing XML code of the same type via Notepad++

Tags: notepad++

Guys i have a lot of codes in xml that currently is in the following way

```
       <Query
            class="type:x-xmb/folder-pixmap"
            key="seg_canyon_preset_001"
            attr="seg_canyon_preset_001"
            src="#seg_canyon_preset_001_item"
            />
```

I need to make it like this

```
    <Query class="type:x-xmb/folder-pixmap" key="seg_canyon_preset_001" attr="seg_canyon_preset_001" src="#seg_canyon_preset_001_item"/>
```

the class=, key= and src= may be different, so I need a way to make all kinds of code in this format be on a single line, even though it may be different, as show below:

```
       <Query
            class="type:x-xmb/module-action"
            key="clock_icon_015_item"
            attr="clock_icon_015_item"
            />
```

Comment: Why is it relevant for you that the attributes are not separated with new lines? The content of the XML file is the same.

Comment: There is a number of lines limit that the PlayStation 3 can read ( those xml files i'm making) so it will not work if it exceeds the amount of lines.

In the same time other codes must have a line break, those ones are the one that works without it, so i need to change just those type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Assuming there're no spaces in attributes**

---

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `(?:<Query|\G(?!/>))\K\s+([^>\r\n]+)`
- Replace with:  `$1`   (A space and `$1`)
- **CHECK** *Match case*
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
(?:             # non capture group
    <Query          # literally
  |               # OR
    \G              # restart from last match position
    (?!/>)          # If not followed by end tag
)               # end group
\K              # forget all we have seen until this position
\s+             # 1 or more spaces, including linebreaks
(               # group 1
    [^>\r\n]+       # 1 or more any character that is not > of linebreak
)               # end group
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]

Comment: if you don't mind, i have a second request.

 Now i need to change <Table key="XXXXX"> to <Table key="XXXXX" include="YYYYY> 

where XXXX and YYYYY are variables

 eg: <Table key="recovery_mode"> to <Table key="recovey_mode" include="shared_actions">

thanks in advance

Comment: @LuanTeles: You're welcome, glad it helps. When you say `XXXX and YYYYY are variables`, how do we know the value of `YYYYY`? You should ask a new question with more details.

Comment: I opened a new thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68749289/how-to-include-text-after-a-variable-tag-text