# How to include text after a variable tag text

Tags: notepad++

i need to include the following:

include="shared_actions" in codes similar to:

```
<View id="music_album_tracks">
    <Attributes>
      <Table key="track_01">
            <Pair key="icon"><String>/dev_hdd0/game/PROTOOLBX/USRDIR/TOOLBOX/extras/online_music/images/black_track.png</String></Pair>
            <Pair key="title"><String>01. Main Theme</String></Pair>
            <Pair key="info"><String>Black™ - OST</String></Pair>
            <Pair key="module_name"><String>webbrowser_plugin</String></Pair> 
            <Pair key="module_action"><String>http://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/1ip0ixd9zgab1bx/Black_-_01._Main_Theme.m4a</String></Pair>
            <Pair key="bar_action"><String>none</String></Pair>
            <Pair key="lbl_half"><String>1</String></Pair>
        </Table>
        <Table key="anyname">
            <Pair key="icon"><String>/dev_hdd0/game/PROTOOLBX/USRDIR/TOOLBOX/extras/online_music/images/black_track.png</String></Pair>
            <Pair key="title"><String>02. Treneska Border Crossing</String></Pair>
            <Pair key="info"><String>Black™ - OST</String></Pair>
            <Pair key="module_name"><String>webbrowser_plugin</String></Pair> 
            <Pair key="module_action"><String>http://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/o0he1n2kx3jygk8/Black_-_02._Treneska_Border_Crossing.m4a</String></Pair>
            <Pair key="bar_action"><String>none</String></Pair>
            <Pair key="lbl_half"><String>1</String></Pair>
        </Table>
    </Attributes>
    <Items>
        <Query class="type:x-xmb/module-action" key="track_01" attr="track_01"/>
        <Query class="type:x-xmb/module-action" key="track_02" attr="track_02"/>
    </Items>
</View>
```

become

```
<View id="music_album_tracks">
    <Attributes>
        <Table key="track_01" include="shared_actions">
            <Pair key="icon"><String>/dev_hdd0/game/PROTOOLBX/USRDIR/TOOLBOX/extras/online_music/images/black_track.png</String></Pair>
            <Pair key="title"><String>01. Main Theme</String></Pair>
            <Pair key="info"><String>Black™ - OST</String></Pair>
            <Pair key="module_name"><String>webbrowser_plugin</String></Pair> 
            <Pair key="module_action"><String>http://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/1ip0ixd9zgab1bx/Black_-_01._Main_Theme.m4a</String></Pair>
            <Pair key="bar_action"><String>none</String></Pair>
            <Pair key="lbl_half"><String>1</String></Pair>
        </Table>
        <Table key="anyname" include="shared_actions">
            <Pair key="icon"><String>/dev_hdd0/game/PROTOOLBX/USRDIR/TOOLBOX/extras/online_music/images/black_track.png</String></Pair>
            <Pair key="title"><String>02. Treneska Border Crossing</String></Pair>
            <Pair key="info"><String>Black™ - OST</String></Pair>
            <Pair key="module_name"><String>webbrowser_plugin</String></Pair> 
            <Pair key="module_action"><String>http://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/o0he1n2kx3jygk8/Black_-_02._Treneska_Border_Crossing.m4a</String></Pair>
            <Pair key="bar_action"><String>none</String></Pair>
            <Pair key="lbl_half"><String>1</String></Pair>
        </Table>
    </Attributes>
    <Items>
        <Query class="type:x-xmb/module-action" key="track_01" attr="track_01"/>
        <Query class="type:x-xmb/module-action" key="track_02" attr="track_02"/>
    </Items>
</View>
```

Summarizing:

I need to include the code include="shared_actions" after the end of the tag  `<Table key="XXXXX">` where XXXXX could be any text

Eg: `<Table key="TEST">`

to

`<Table key="TEST" include="shared_actions">`

text to allow me to post it, as it is saying i need to add more details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `<table key="[^"]+"`
- Replace with: `$0 include="shared_actions"`
- **UNCHECK** *Match case*
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
<table key="        # literally
[^"]+               # 1 or more character that is not a double quote
"                   # double quote
```

**Replacement:**

```
$0                              # the whole match
 include="shared_actions"       # note the space at the beginning
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]